Liquibase: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index when not in classpath
My project structure is as follows:
project
|___project-web
|___project-service
|___project-database

project-web is a spring boot project where the application class is. Project-database is not a spring boot project, but just contains a build.gradle and our liquibase changelogs. Now, in project-web I have integration tests that need to run the liquibase changelogs. When I copy my changelogs into project-web/src/test/resources and set the change-log parameter as change-log: classpath:db/db-migrations/changelog.xml this works as expected.
However, for obvious reasons I want to avoid copying the chanelogs when they're already present in the project. For this I tried setting the change-log parameter as change-log: file:../project-database/db-migrations/changelog.xml which results in this exception: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 4: file:../project-database/db-migrations/v2024.07.1/2024.07.16-initial.xml.
So the path itself is correct, liquibase can find the files, but it fails with said exception unless I copy the very same files to my test/resources folder. I also tried arbitrarily changing the order of my changelog files to see if it was one file, but the exception is always the exact same.
EDIT: I am not 100% sure I did it correctly, but I tried following Nikos' advice:
In build.gradle of project-database I added:
sourceSets {
main {
    resources {
        srcDir 'db-migrations'
    }
}}

Then I added a dependency in project-web on project-database and changed the liquibase parameter to change-log: classpath:project-database/db-migrations/changelog.xml.
However, this doesn't work and the test fails with Caused by: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: ERROR: The file 'classpath:project-database/db-migrations/changelog.xml' was not found.
Did I do something incorrectly?

If project-database is configured to include the changeset files in the jar, if those files are e.g. the changelog itself under <jar root>/db/db-migrations/changelog.xml and if web depends on database (it probably should), then classpath:db/db-migrations/changelog.xml should be able to locate them. Have you tried it?

@NikosParaskevopoulos thanks, I tried to do that, but it didn't work, maybe I am doing something wrong. I updated the original question to include what I tried.

I do not know Gradle, so I could be wildly mistaken. But if srcDir is what I think, i.e. a root in the project source tree, the files under which will be included in the JAR, then the path you specify in the configuration is wrong. Try only the part of the path to the changelog.xml that is under db-migrations - maybe just changelog.xml. Experiment a bit - e.g. I do not know if it needs a leading /, so try both!

You can add liquibase.properties file in project level and then define the changelog file inside it like:
# Enter the path for your changelog file.
changeLogFile=src/main/resources/db/changelog-master.yaml

This would let liquibase know where to find the file. When you do not give this it will look in the project's resources folder
